# Does TDengine support to modify the TTL afterwards?

Tags: sql, tdengine

I create a super table with the following statement:

```
CREATE STABLE `gps` (`st` TIMESTAMP, `loc_type` INT, `access_address` VARCHAR(200), `t` TIMESTAMP, `lat` FLOAT, `lng` FLOAT, `alt` FLOAT, `dir` FLOAT, `spd` FLOAT, `acc` INT) TAGS (`dev_id` BIGINT) ttl 30;
```

If I create the super table with a specified TTL(30), and I want to change the TTL value later, how can I change it? I can't change it with the `alter stable xx` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this option value cannot be modified since a database was created.

See https://docs.tdengine.com/taos-sql/database/#change-database-configuration.